# Avro ReflectData override record definition to logical type

Tags: java, avro, parquet, avro-tools

Am using ReflectData to generate a schema from a Java class. 
One of the fields is

```
private LocalDate localDate;
```

and the reflectData generates equivalent code as a record

```
   {  
     "name":"localDate",
     "type":[  
        "null",
        {  
           "type":"record",
           "name":"LocalDate",
           "namespace":"java.time",
           "fields":[  

           ]
        }
     ],
     "default":null
  }
```

I would like to override the behavior on the class using some operations on the schema below so that

```
 final Schema schema = ReflectData.AllowNull.get().getSchema(cls). ?;
```

the resultant schema is referencing the logical type date as below instead

```
 {
    "name" : "localDate",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "int",
      "logicalType" : "date"
    } ],
    "default" : null
  }
```

...

Added some more attempts

```
 // given a java object
 @Data
 public class JavaPojo {


    @AvroEncode(using = DateAsLongEncoding.class)
    private Date javaDate;

    @AvroEncode(using = DateAsLongEncoding.class)
    private LocalDateTime javaLocalDateTime;

 }
 ...
 // and an instance of it
 JavaPojo javaPojo = new JavaPojo();
 javaPojo.setJavaDate(new Date());
 javaPojo.setJavaLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime.now())
...
 // use relfection to generate the schema and eventually store it as parquet with a logicalType mapping
 Schema schema = ReflectData.AllowNull.get().getSchema(JavaPojo.class);
 // attempted to toggle on timeSupport as well
 GenericData timeSupport = new GenericData();
 timeSupport.addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.DateConversion());

 ParquetWriter<JavaPojo> avroParquetWriter =  
                        AvroParquetWriter.<JavaPojo> builder(fsPath)
                                                .withSchema(schema)
                                                .withDataModel(ReflectData.get())
.withDataModel(timeSupport)
.withCompressionCodec(ompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                                                .build();

...
 // fails with the below when no timeSupport is set
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
or similarly with LocalDateTime

// fails with the below when timeSupport is added
java.lang.ClassCastException: JavaPojo cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord
```

Comment: Avro 1.8.2 uses JodaTime, not `java.time`, so that might be causing issues

Comment: even if i were to use jodaTime then it will not create a loicalType date but create a type record with namespace org.joda.time and fields for iLocalMillis and iChronology

Comment: To be honest, I have little experience with the reflect api, but I know some coworkers take advantage of the CustomEncoder interface for converting Date types into Longs Avro has a built-in `DateAsLongEncoding`, and you'd annotate with `@AvroEncode`

Comment: attempted with @AvroEncode and timeSupport ..and ran into some other issues

Comment: I believe `LocalDateTime` would need you to define your own `CustomEncoder` for how to handle it